# How can I instantiate a contract from a factory and, in the same call, send msg.value to it?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, address.transfer

WHAT I WANT TO DO:  call another contract's constructor function, instantiate that contract, and subsequently send Ether to it in the same function.
WHAT HAPPENS: an instance of the other contract gets created, and Ether is transferred, but none of the functions on the newly created contract work. I get `call to SmartGift.{function name} errored: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when I try to do anything on the new contract.
PROBLEM FUNCTION:

```
function createSmartGift(address _recipient, uint32 _expiry, string _donorMsg) public payable returns(address){
        address newGift;
        newGift = new SmartGift(_recipient, msg.sender, _expiry, _donorMsg);
        giftExists[newGift] = true;  

        uint id = gifts.push(Gift(newGift, _donorMsg,false, _expiry));
        giftToOwner[id-1] = _recipient;
        recipientGiftCount[_recipient]++;
        donorGiftCount[msg.sender]++;

        newGift.transfer(address(this).balance); // I WANT TO THIS, BUT GET ERROR

        return newGift;
    }
```

OTHER NOTES: I've tried both `address(this).balance` and `msg.value`. And the target contract has a payable fallback function.
Also, everything works fine if I separate out the newGift.transfer() into a separate function that I have to call separately. That's my backup plan, but I want the customer to only click once, not twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that isn't working, but as a workaround, you can just make `SmartGift`'s constructor payable and do this:

```
address newGift = (new SmartGift).value(address(this).balance)(_recipient,
    msg.sender, _expiry, _donorMsg);
```

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation on this address.value()(args) syntax? Thanks.

Comment: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/control-structures.html#creating-contracts-via-new